# Live feed of an updating file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file

I have a php file that prints the last 50 lines of a txt file. However, this file gets appended every second and would like to view a "live feed" of the action. How can this be done? This is the code for the php file:

```
<?php
$filename = '/home/duke/aa/servers/df/var/logs.log';  //about 500MB
$output = shell_exec('exec tail -n50 ' . $filename);  //only print last 50 lines
echo str_replace(PHP_EOL, '<br />', $output);         //add newlines
?>
```

Comment: use fseek(file,offset,whence)

Comment: I was looking for a client solution like ajax/jquery

Comment: client solution can't access your server's absolute path.

Comment: this php file is in /var/www/, reading a file at the location $filename works just fine

Comment: Can you use a database instead of a text file? Using just the text file, it's going to be more difficult to keep track of the last line that was displayed and only show the newer ones. Or are the lines numbered somehow?

Comment: @jeroen unfortunately the server is just spitting out logs and appending to this text file. A db would probably require major reworking on how the server operates, which I have little clue.

Comment: Well, you can rewrite the php to check for the last line displayed and make sure you only show the newer ones. If necessary of course...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With ajax. If you need cross-browser compatibility, replace the AJAX function I provided with one from a library like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
<html><head></head><body>
<div id="feed"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var refreshtime=10;
function tc()
{
asyncAjax("GET","myphpfile.php",Math.random(),display,{});
setTimeout(tc,refreshtime);
}
function display(xhr,cdat)
{
 if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
 {
   document.getElementById("feed").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
 }
}
function asyncAjax(method,url,qs,callback,callbackData)
{
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    //xmlhttp.cdat=callbackData;
    if(method=="GET")
    {
        url+="?"+qs;
    }
    var cb=callback;
    callback=function()
    {
        var xhr=xmlhttp;
        //xhr.cdat=callbackData;
        var cdat2=callbackData;
        cb(xhr,cdat2);
        return;
    }
    xmlhttp.open(method,url,true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=callback;
    if(method=="POST"){
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xmlhttp.send(qs);
    }
    else
    {
            xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
}
tc();
</script>
</body></html>
```

You will have to create a php file called myphpfile.php (or change the code above to reference the correct file) and put the following in it (as taken from your question):

```
<?php
$filename = '/home/duke/aa/servers/df/var/logs.log';  //about 500MB
$output = shell_exec('exec tail -n50 ' . $filename);  //only print last 50 lines
echo str_replace(PHP_EOL, '<br />', $output);         //add newlines
?>
```

Comment: This looked promising, however I get a blank screen with this code

Comment: Did you replace myphpfile.php with the location of the file containing the code provided in your question?

Comment: Yes, I have. I have 2 files now, one with my short code above, and your code. Do I point my browser to your code or my code with a header like `<script src="js.js">`?

Comment: Hm, no luck. http://209.141.56.244/test/query.html is where your code is, and http://209.141.56.244/test/logtee.php is my file

Comment: Oh, I see the problem: you're missing a </div> after the <div id="feed">, and a </script> at the end. Try recopying my code again, I made a few changes.

Comment: Now you just have to change the filename again (myphpfile.php to logtee.php) and I think it'll work-- it's showing ton of requests to the non-existent myphpfile.php in my test.

Comment: Nevermind, it worked! Thanks very much. A million gold stars for you :)

Comment: +1 Although using ajax and a timeout function is the way to go, the php is going to be a lot more complicated to show just the new lines instead of the 50 last lines (to avoid doubles and / or missing entries).

Answer (score 0):

check using php, Efficient last lines file reading in PHP

http://mydebian.blogdns.org/?p=197

or

if tail is installed on the server, a quick

```
$logfile = '/home/duke/aa/servers/df/var/logs.log';
$numlines = "50";
$cmd = “tail -$numlines '$logfile'”;
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
echo $output;
```

Comment: Was looking for an answer for a webrowser to point to this file and view the file in real time.