# PHP: Printing out status messages during runtime

Tags: php, runtime, status

I'm developing a long running php script that compiles scraped information from multiple sources, organizes them, and caches them in a database.

As this script has a very high runtime, I'd like to print out **runtime status reports** in order to track the progress.

```
for ($i = 1; $i<= 10; $i++) {
    echo "Starting iteration #$i\n";
    set_time_limit(40);
    echo "Time Limit set, starting 10 second sleep.\n";
    sleep(10);
    echo "Finishing iteration #$i\n\n";
}
echo "Iterations Finished.";
```

would output:

> Starting iteration #1
>
> Time Limit set, starting 10 second sleep

then wait 10 seconds and output:

> Finishing iteration #1
>
> Starting iteration #2
>
> Time Limit set, starting 10 second sleep

then right before the php finishes parsing, it will output:

> Iterations Finished.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running PHP from the CLI you can output directly to stdout, without having to wait for the script
to end, using :

```
$handle = fopen('php://stdout', 'r');
fwrite($handle, $output);
```

If run from CGI, which would be really bad for a script like this, you would have to change how the buffer acts with flush();

Comment: My php is currently installed as CGI, what makes it bad?

Comment: `function flush2 (){
    echo(str_repeat(' ',256));
    if (ob_get_length()){            
        @ob_flush();
        @flush();
        @ob_end_flush();
    }    
    @ob_start();
}` was the solution in my case.

Comment: Don't know why, but on my current environment `echo` calls were buffered, so I get my output only when script ends. Your solution helped, because `fwrite` to stdout shows messages immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing the runtime status reports to a file, then viewing live updates of the file using ajax, per this question: [Live feed of an updating file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7290515/902654)