# How to read a file in real time with PHP and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to read a txt file in real time and update the new lines added in my front end. The text file holds the logs data of two users. I've tried a bit to find a way to work but both the php script as the js don't work as I want to.

**JS Script**

```
  function ShowNewMessages(res, curr, end) {
    // build the front end
    var newdiv1 = "<div class=\"message\"> <div class=\"own-avatar-message\" style=\"background-image: url("+res[curr][4].replace(/\\\//g, "/")+");\"></div><div class=\"own-message2\"><div class=\"own-message\"><p>" +  res[curr][3]  +"</p></div><div class=\"message-timestamp\"> "+ res[curr][1] +" • "+res[curr][2] +"</div></div> </div>"; 

    $( newdiv1 ).insertAfter( $( ".message" ).last());
    var height = 0;
    $('.message').each(function(i, value){
        height += parseInt($(this).height());
    });

    height += '';

    $('div').animate({scrollTop: height});

    // check if there is another messsage or checkagain for new messages             
    curr++;
    if (curr <= end) ShowNewMessages(res, curr, end);
    else {setTimeout(function() {GetNewMesssages()}, 10000);}
}



function GetNewMesssages() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: "../lib/GetMesssage.php",
        data: "friend=" + MsgFriend,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false, 
        success:function(data){
            // check error state
            if (data[0] != "Error") {
                var start = 0;
                var end = data.length-1; // minus one for the new line
                if (end > 0 ) ShowNewMessages(data, start, end-1);
                else setTimeout(function() {GetNewMesssages()}, 10000);

            }
            else alert('some error message');
            }
        });   
}
```

**GetMesssage.php**

```
<?php 

    session_start();

    // get the requirements for the file name
    $MyEmail = $_SESSION['login'];
    $FriendEmail = $_POST['friend'];

    if (strcmp($MyEmail, $FriendEmail) < 0) {
        $FileName = $MyEmail.'-'.$FriendEmail.'.txt';
    }
    else {
        $FileName = $FriendEmail.'-'.$MyEmail.'.txt';
    }


    $File = fopen('data/'.$FileName, "r") or die(json_encode(array_push($messages, "Error")));

    // count the lines exist in the file
    $count = 0;
    while(!feof($File)){
        $tmp = fgets($File);
        $count++;
    }

    // if the session var that holds the offset position is not set 
    // or has value more than the lines of text file
    if (!isset($_SESSION['pos']) || $_SESSION['pos'] >= $count) {
       $_SESSION['pos'] = 0; // back to the beginning
    } 

    // the array that holds the logs data
    $messages = array(); 

    // move the pointer to the current position
    fseek($File, $_SESSION['pos']);

    // read the file
    while(!feof($File)){
        $msg = fgets($File);
        $msg1 = explode("<!@#@>", $msg);
        array_push($messages, $msg1);
        $_SESSION['pos']++;
    }

    // get the current offset position
    //$_SESSION['pos'] = ftell($File);

    // return the array
    echo json_encode($messages);

    fclose($File)
?>
```

## Explainig

Assume that the routine starts for the first time when we call the `GetNewMesssages()` function. The function will fire the php and get the data from the file.

Next if the data holds somenthing, the return array isn't empty, we execute the `ShowNewMessages()` function and we update the front end.

When we finish we start another `GetNewMesssages()` callback.

## What I want

I want to check the file for new added lines every N seconds and update my front end.

## Problems

I have the problems both in php and js script. I didn't want to add two questions.

**In PHP**

I didn't found how to use the `ftell()` to get only the new added lines. As the script works like it is, I get constantly all the file into my array in every update.

**In JS**

In JS I have problems synchronize the ajax call. That means in every call of the `GetNewMessages()` function I get 2-3 calls again of the function. It has to do with `setTimeout()` but I also couldn't find how to set the call back.

## UPDATE

An example of the text file I read from:

```
line_id <BreakString> some data <BreakString> blah blah

another_line_id <BreakString> some_other data <BreakString> blah blah 2
```

*Note:  doesn't mean anything. It's just separate the contents to array.*

## UPDATE 2

After a moderator notice, I'll small my question only to find what is the best method to read a file in real time keeping my structure.

Comment: Looks like you don't need PHP for reading the file, but yes, you need something to write it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar you mean what exactly? (I have another procedure that updates the file)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290515/live-feed-of-an-updating-file

Comment: Should probably start with why you need to do this from text file and not use some type of database which would be much simpler at server vs rolling your own

Comment: @charlietfl I have thought it before. I figure out that this is the best solution for now. In the next update , when my project finish, I'll start to think about it. Anyway it's just for practice, it doesn't hurt

Comment: That's fair but also keep in mind that doing this through data base isn't much more complex and is definitely less load on server

Comment: Also get rid of `async: false` ... it is a terrible practice and is deprecated by browsers and will break in the near future

Comment: @charlietfl I know. Please make an answer will all the correction I need to do (as well as with some explanation please) if you have the time :)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP

In PHP [`fseek()`](http://php.net/fseek) sets the file pointer to a specific *byte* offset in the file. The assumption you appear to be making in your code is that `fseek()` will set the pointer to a specific line in the file.

Assuming your messages do not contain any linefeed characters (*no such truth is founded in this code*), you could just use [`file()`](http://php.net/file) instead to load the entire file into an array in PHP and determine the line offset you need that way.

For example...

```
$file = file($fileName);
$mssages = array_slice($file, $_SESSION['pos']);
```

This would give you an array of all lines in the file starting at `$_SESSION['pos']` line offset.

---

#### Refactoring your existing PHP code

To refactor your existing code instead you could modify the following loop to stop reading at the point where it hits `$_SESSION['pos']` and thus continue your logic of loading new messages from that point on...

```
$count = 0;
while(!feof($File)){
    $tmp = fgets($File);
    $count++;
}
```

Instead you do this...

```
$count = 0;
while(!feof($File) || $count < $_SESSION['pos']){
    $tmp = fgets($File);
    $count++;
}
```

Now remove the `fseek($File, $_SESSION['pos'])` part and your second loop should pick up at the line where you expect it to.

---

#### File Format

If the file storing these messages is intended to be a line-separated format, where each line in the file represents exactly one message (*this appears to be the assumption you are making in your code*) then the safest way to avoid the message contents itself from corrupting your file is to encode the message contents in a manner that does not allow for linefeed characters in the message payload. Examples of such encodings include ***JSON***, and ***Base64***.

The latter will give you about 33% more inflated storage cost, but both will be safe for a line-separated file format.

---

## Javascript

It is unclear why your javascript logic uses `curr` and `end` to determine whether or not it should use `setTimeout()`. If you want a global loop to constantly check for new data every 10 seconds you should be calling `setInterval(GetNewMesssages, 10000)` from the global scope once instead of using `setTimeout()` conditionally. In your code if the condition that the current message is the last message found you will no longer call your PHP again from js to check for new messages, which clearly isn't what you want. The difference between `setTimeout` and `setInterval` is that `setTimeout` is only triggered **once** when the timer is reached, whereas `setInterval` will **continuously** trigger the callback at the given interval.

Comment: I use `setTimeout` cause I want to be able to stop some procedures and restart them again. It depends on the user how will navigate to the web app. As for the  linefeed characters you mention I will update my question with a sample of the text file to see if everything is all right.

Comment: Both `setTimeout` and `setInterval` timers can be stopped. They each return an *ID*, which can be supplied to [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) or [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) in order to stop the timer.

Comment: Also I don't want to read the entire file into the memory. If the files gets more than 100 mb then well have problems.

Comment: Understandable, which is why my answer furnishes you with both an option to easily solve the problem in a new and transparent manner, as well as one that simply refactors your existing code. Both solutions were intended for effectiveness and not efficiency.

Comment: The manipulate code for php didn't worked. I get again all the array. But why?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "_the manipulate code for php_" or what is meant by "_it didn't work_". If you are looking for someone to help you debug code you must be prepared to supply them with 3 things: 1) The code exhibiting the bug, 2) What you expected that code to do, 3) What that code actually did that you didn't expect.

Comment: It returns me an empty array. Can you please post the hole code?

Comment: I'm not sure which code was not **whole** that you would like me to post to you. Perhaps the reason you are getting an empty array is that `$_SESSION['pos']` is at the end of the file or the file itself is empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101479/discussion-between-georgegkas-and-sherif).